# How do I get the first character of a string from a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I have this line of code:

```
if (strcmp(n->data.name[i], searchName[i]) == 0)
```

I'm sure it's incorrect, how do i examine the first character of name which is stored in a linked list?(the error is "n->data.name[i]"
Thanks

This is the rest of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct record
{   
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char telephone[20];
}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;


void search() {
    Node *n = head;
    Node *next = n;
    int valid = 0;
    int length2;
    int valid2 = 0;
    int valid3 = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char searchName[20];

    printf("  Enter name, and/or surname, or tel no.   : ");
    gets();
    gets(searchName);

    length2 = strlen(searchName);
    for (int i = 0; i < length2; i++)
    {
        valid2 = 0;
        while (isspace(searchName[i]));
        {
            if (strcmp(n->data.name[i], searchName[i]) == 0)
            {
                valid2 = 1; 
                count++;
            }
        }       
    }
```

...

Comment: try `n->data.name[i]`

Comment: depends on your implimentation of linked list. Show struct declaration.

Comment: If `n->data.name` is a string, then `n->data.name[i]` is a single character, and you don't compare those with a ***string*** comparison function.

Comment: `n->data.name)[i]` - that is definitely *not* the entire error message, which should *always* be reported *completely* and *exactly* as it appears in your configuration. Nor do we know anything about your code besides the single line presented here. We only see what you show us; we're not mind readers.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first of these two statements: `gets(); gets(searchName);` ?

Comment: gets(); is to remove the white space
gets(searchName); is for the user to enter a name to search with

Comment: Well it does not compile. Did you `#include` the proper file headers? I can't see any!

Comment: Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you have tried.

Comment: `while (isspace(searchName[i]));` what is this supposed to do (except loop forever. (or don't loop at all))

Comment: I had to allow throw an exception for the software to read get()

Comment: `"error C2198: 'gets' : too few arguments for call."` The code does not compile, so how can you get an exception error?

Comment: while (isspace(searchName[i]));
when there is a space in the string, the program stops.

Comment: I would not call that *stopping*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the starting spaces in your search query to perform as a wild card. Your strcmp needs a minor update then: replace `if (strcmp(n->data.name[i], searchName[i]) == 0)` with `if (strcmp(n->data.name + i, searchName +i) == 0)`